# I trying to install apache zeppelin, by running ./bin/install-interpreter.sh --all, but am lost.. kinda don't know where to start

Tags: python, windows, jupyter-notebook, apache-zeppelin

I want to install Apache Zeppelin on windows 10 but am lost. I want to use zeppelin for my data science projects.. but installing this tool and setting a git repo is complicated for me. I have already downloaded and unzipped the zeppelin installation file.
please is there anyone who can assist me?

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to install zeppelin in linux, or you can use it via docker. http://zeppelin.apache.org/download.html#using-the-official-docker-image